# I cannot save into excel the result of entire loop but only the last iteration

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I would like to save the results of the entire iteration into an excel file but at the moment I save only the last run. Why is this happening and how to solve it?
I added a line 'append' but then I get an error message..

```
path = '../'
df1=[]

for file in os.listdir(path):
 if file.endswith('.txt'):
     with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as f:
         df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", header=0,usecols=[0,11])
         df.columns = ["x", "y"]

         abs_PAR=[]
         mean1=[]

         for (x, y) in df.iteritems():

          abs_PAR = sum(y.iloc[49:350]) / len(y.iloc[49:350])

          mean1.append(abs_PAR)

          newrow = {0:abs_PAR}
          df1 = df1.append(newrow)
          print(newrow)

writer = ExcelWriter('df1.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Error message:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have defined `newrow` but you are appending `new_row`. Variable names are different

Comment: @RaghavaDhanya, thanks! so stupid mistake. However, now that I changed it, I get the following error:     df1 = df1.append(newrow)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the assign operator (=) with append. Try changing

```
df1 = df1.append(newrow)
```

to

```
df1.append(newrow)
```